# Notation indicating a number is negative, positive, or zero.

Tags: notation

We can indicate that $x$ is negative by writing $x<0$, that it is positive by writing $x>0$, or that it is zero by writing $x=0$.

Out of curiosity, are there other notations, such as an overset or underset, to say the same?

Comment: Those conditions are precisely the *definitions* of a number being negative, positive, or zero. You can always use or create equivalent statements, such as $x\in\mathbb R^+$ or $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = 1$ (the latter referring to the *signum* function which takes values $-1$, $1$, or $0$ corresponding to $x$ being negative, positive, or zero -- essentially, the "sign" of $x$.

Comment: @MPW Sounds like a great answer. If you post it as one, I will mark it. I definitely see how $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ makes sense.

Comment: Consider $x\in\mathbb R^{>0}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Comment converted to answer]*

Those conditions are precisely the *definitions* of a number being negative, positive, or zero.

You can always use or create equivalent statements, such as $x\in\mathbb R^+$ or $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = 1$ (the latter referring to the *signum* function which takes values $-1$, $1$, or $0$ corresponding to $x$ being negative, positive, or zero -- essentially, the "sign" of $x$).